# Obtener valores ArrayList de objetos java

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito obtener los valores y trabajar con ellos de un `ArrayList` de objetos que se rellena mediante un query sql que se ejecuta sobre el servidor. Os muestro un poco la estructura para que me entendáis mejor:

Tengo la siguiente declaración:

```
List<Object[]> lista=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

La cual se rellena así:

```
lista.addAll(query.getResultList());
```

La cosa es que no consigo acceder al contenido de los objetos de ninguna manera, os muestro un poco resumido el código que tengo:

```
Iterator<Object[]> it = lista.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){

        Object[] item=it.next();
    }
```

Y hasta ahí he probado a sacar de item de mil maneras diferentes el contenido y no lo consigo.

Comment: Parece que lo estás haciendo mal - `query.getResultList()` devuelve un objeto `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. `Object[]` es un array de objetos genéricos de diversos tipos ¿? ¿Podrías explicar mejor con ejemplos la estructura que quieres guardar aquí: `List<Object[]> lista=new ArrayList<Object[]>();` y lo que devuelve en sí: `query.getResultList()`? Da la impresión de que intentas meter arrays dentro de arrays, ¿por qué?

Comment: Muestra la sentencia que se está ejecutando.

Comment: Con lo que muestras no parece que haya ningún error, pero como no sabemos exactamente qué código pruebas y qué comportamiento observas ("no lo consigo" no da mucha información), va a ser muy difícil ayudarte. Revisa como crear un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Creo que primero necesitas asegurarte que el query te está generando algo.

Asumo que el query o consulta te genera una java.util.Collection, porque la agregas a un ArrayList.

Para ver si te está generando algo la consulta puedes iterar esa colección en lugar del ArrayList, así:

```
java.util.Collection coleccion = query.getResultList();
if (coleccion == null) {
    System.out.println("la consulta retorna nulo");
}
else if (coleccion.size() == 0) {
    System.out.println("la consulta genero una collección vacía");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Se obtuvieron "+coleccion.size()+" objetos, los mostramos:");
    java.util.Iterator iterador = coleccion.iterator();
    while (iterador.hasNext()) {
        Object objeto = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("objeto:"+objeto);
        if (objeto != null) {
           System.out.println("       clase="+objeto.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```